# Transmission fluid leak 1993 5.0 V8 F150 Engine

Tags: ford, automatic-transmission, f-150

When I add transmission fluid, it leaks out below. It looks like it is collecting around the pan, but also forward.

I am asking to see if someone thinks changing the pan won't cover the leak.

[image: Passenger side of transmission pan]

[image: Transmission leak #2]

[image: Transmission leak #3]

[image: Transmission leak #4]

Update 5/25/15

Cleaned up around the pan and forward. The cork seal around the pan is bone dry. But it looks like the leak is coming from this rubber gasket. That's bad, right?

[image: Transmission rubber cap]

Comment: The rubber seal is just a plug to keep the dust out. The hole can be used as an inspection port. There should be *no* fluid on the other side of that plug, so since there is, there is nothing good about the drip coming from there.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that I think it could be the front main seal in the transmission, doing the pan gasket is not only an easier job to do, but you can also change the filter while you are there. If the pan gasket fixes it, you're golden. If it doesn't, changing out the pan gasket and filter is not expensive and could probably use the change anyway. If you don't want to go this route, I'd suggest you clean everything off and actually **see** where it's leaking from. That way you'll know for sure. Just looking at it, though, my bet is on the front seal.

Comment: I checked my Chilton and Haynes but did not find reference to the front main seal. I am guessing that is because the job is outside the scope of a home mechanic.

Comment: @Slobvrflw - It can also be called the front pump seal. It's the seal which goes around the torque converter where it enters the transmission to keep it sealed. And you are right ... this is beyond what most home mechanics would (should) be willing to deal with. The biggest piece of equipment you need to make the fix (if this is it) is a transmission jack. Most people don't own one.

Answer (score 1):

The existing oil residue will make it difficult to tell the source of the leak. I suggest you clean the entire area (copious amounts of brake cleaner usually does a decent job) and then run the vehicle a little to see if you can trace the source of the leak.